# Calling controller method without a view associated with it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to write a quick plugin for my website where given: `localhost:port/email/sendemail/foo@bar.com` will send out an email.

Is it possible to write an email controller with a method of emailsend that can be called from anywhere in the application or even the address bar without having to define a view or redirect for it?

I have tried the following

```
public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendEmail(string email)
        {
            ....Code
            EmailSender.NewEmail(email);  
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen after the POST?  If you don't want to redirect or return a view, are you wanting to handle it like an AJAX request?

Comment: @ZachM. Yeah, don't get confuse, it's common to have methods with no corresponding view. I think the beast scenario is to use `AJAX` as `maelstrom` suggested and return `JsonResult` with something like `"Your e-mail was send successfully"` or something like this.

Comment: I think that would be the best way to handle it now that you mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue, using a generic JsonResult was the way to go.

```
 [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult SendEmail(string guid)
            {
               //Validation here
                return Json("Email Sent", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
            }
```